# Windows App or Local Web App

Tags: .net, asp.net, windows, architecture

I have a new project, requirement are:

- Organised groups of users at multiple geo locations answer test questions using this software.
- We cannot rely on consistent internet connection, in case it goes down during test.

My question's are:

**Q1.** Based on assuming no internet connection, I guess I have 2 options?:

1. Locally installed .Net Web App at each assesment center.
2. .Net Windows App at each assesment center.

**Q2.** Either way I am looking to store results as XML on a local server top be pushed over to central database by the test administrator when internet is available. is this correct?

Any advice would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks.
Code Warrior

Answer (score 6):

Here's the [Smart Client Architecture and Design Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998506.aspx) from MSDN.

You may wish to read [Chapter 4 — Occasionally Connected Smart Clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998482.aspx)

Also, my mate advised me that "[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)" is worth a look at.  Apparently with CouchDB you can use it locally, offline, and then replicate later.